# Count the number of ways to insert x different element into a two sequances one of size m and the other of size n

Tags: combinatorics

I am doing competetive programming task called "Ptaszki"
Its easy dfs with some observations.
But i came across the following problem:

I have two sequances of size n and m respectively and i want to count the number of ways to insert x different elements into this sequances

You can choose for every element to which sequance it will go.
You can also insert every element to the start or the end of the sequance.
I dont have any idea how to solve it.
Could you please help me?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Let one of sequences is "a" and one of elements to insert is "a", are two "aa" sequences formed by inserting element "a" to the start of the sequence "a" and to the end of the sequence counted as two different ways?